# Build for both browser and node with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm writing my first module. Basically the code is exactly the same for both the browser and node.js versions. The only difference is that the browser uses XmlHttpRequest whilst node.js uses http module.

Here is an example similar to what I'm trying to do.

```
// test.js

const urlHelper = require('url');

class XmlHttpHandler {
    constructor(xhr) {
        this.xhr = xhr;
    }

    call(url, callback) {
        this.xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        this.xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if(this.xhr.readyState === 4) {
                callback(this.xhr.status);
            }
        }
        this.xhr.send();
    }
}

class HttpHandler {
    constructor(http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    call(url, callback) {
        const method = "GET";
        const { hostname, port, path } = urlHelper.parse(url);        

        this.http.request({ method, hostname, port, path }, 
        (response) => {
            response.on('data', (chunk) => { });
            response.on('end', () => { callback(response.statusCode); });
        }).end();
    }
}

module.exports = () => typeof navigator !== 'undefined' ? 
    new XmlHttpHandler(new XMLHttpRequest()) : 
    new HttpHandler(require('http'));
```

Webpack config is like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = [
    { 
        target: 'web',
        entry: './test.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'test.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'umd',
            library: 'test'
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "sandbox")
        }
    },
    { 
        target: 'node',
        entry: './test.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'test.node.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
        }
    }
];
```

If I try to use the module from node.js like this, it works:

```
const test = require('./dist/test.node');
test().call('http://localhost:8080', (status) => { console.log(status); });
```

I would like to use just one js for both browser and node versions.
Is there a way with webpack to build a single js which works for both the browser and node?
I hope it's a bit clearer now. ;-)

Thanks,
Massimo

Comment: SOLVED. Simply I needed to set `libraryTarget: "umd"` in webpack.config.js and exclude the http and https modules with the **externals** config.

Comment: Hi Massimo, welcome to SO, good question. Feel free to answer your own question, people arriving here will probably see it more quickly than in a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I am just picturing your situation and I think you could achieve your objective using the `ProvidePlugin`. You will define the same variable (`API`?) for both modules (XHR or http) and your application will use that variable defined.
There's also a condition, both your modules **must expose the same functions**